# Auslogics Boostspeed 8 review

Tags: speed

Do any professional IT technicians have an opinion of **`Auslogics Boostspeed 8`**? http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/boost-speed/

It was advertised on **`speedtest.net`**

It is displaying as **`Severe`** some **`System Stability`** problems that I don't experience.

It is also displaying as **`High Speed Loss`** under **`Computer Speed`**, when the computer speed is fine, hence I'm questioning the developer's professionalism in my own mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed and, after a mere 30 minutes, uninstalled the trial version. The features are so crippled that it is impossible to make a valid judgement about how good or bad it is at what it is supposed to do. However, it's what it shouldn't be doing that is by far its worst feature.

It kept popping up ads for an immediate purchase with scarey numbers about what a mess my PC was (it is not). In the end I got so fed up I tried to close it down. Another box popped up with even scarier warnings and the 'invitation' - more like a demand with menace - to 'buy now'. Closed the box and tried to close the program again - WTF? back comes the scarey-buy now box. Had to CTRL+ALT+DEL and use Task Manager to kill it in the end.

That wasn't even it's last shot. I went to uninstall it - nope, it interrupts the uninstall process with a demend to connect to Auslogics' site to 'give feedback'. You can close it but as soon as you try to continue the uninstall it reappears. It couldn't autoconnect because I hadn't fired up the mobile BB; in the end I did so and watched as it began to load a page with a URL that included the names of several other programs as well as BoostSpeed. Didn't wait to see what other crap they would pul, I simply shut the browser then the MBB software. The uninstall then sort-of worked, except the program's uninstaller left a lot of files (perhaps all of them) and many registry entries. I used a third-party uninstaller I'm trialling (IOBIT's) clean this garbage off my machine.

I tried this as it had a supposed 'special offer' on another program I was thinking of buying (that's about to be uninstalled). I shall never download anything from this bunch of crooks and cowboys again. No reputable company uses such tactics, some of which are akin to those of malware. Indeed I have since learned that Malwarebytes have it red-flagged as a a PUP.

In summary, don't touch anything Auslogics offers even wearing a full-body P3 biohazard suit and using a ten-foot pole.